# How to obtain a convergent solution iteratively for a linear system of equations

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, numerics, linear-algebra, iterators

I am working on a problem that requires an iterative procedure to solve a linear system of equations, the system of equations in matrix form is:

$$\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
r_{11} & r_{12} & r_{13} & \cdots & r_{1j} \\
r_{21} & r_{22} & r_{23} & \cdots & r_{2j} \\
r_{31} & r_{32} & r_{33} & \cdots & r_{3j} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
r_{i1} & r_{i2} & r_{i3} & \cdots & r_{ij}
\end{bmatrix}}_\textit{R}
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1} & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & a_{2} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a_{3} & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & a_{j}
\end{bmatrix}}_\textit{A}
+
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1} & b_{2} & b_{3} & \cdots & b_{j} \\
b_{1} & b_{2} & b_{3} & \cdots & b_{j} \\
b_{1} & b_{2} & b_{3} & \cdots & b_{j} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
b_{1} & b_{2} & b_{3} & \cdots & b_{j}
\end{bmatrix}}_\textit{B}
=
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
c_{1} & c_{1} & c_{1} & \cdots & c_{1} \\
c_{2} & c_{2} & c_{2} & \cdots & c_{2} \\
c_{3} & c_{3} & c_{3} & \cdots & c_{3} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
c_{i} & c_{i} & c_{i} & \cdots & c_{i}
\end{bmatrix}}_\textit{C}\\
R_{i, j}A_{j, j} + B_{i, j} = C_{i, j}
$$

Now matrix R is fully known (input), matrices A, B, C are unknown. I am working on an iterative procedure in which I provide initial guesses for A and B, then calculate C. The iteration is to be carried out till I get a converged value for C (output I require). So far no luck in choosing the initial guess too.

To illustrate the problem I have given an example for a $2 \times 2$ matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
r_{11} & r_{12} \\
r_{21} & r_{22} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1} & 0 \\
0 & a_{2} \\
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1} & b_{2} \\
b_{1} & b_{2} \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
c_{1} & c_{1} \\
c_{2} & c_{2} \\
\end{bmatrix}\\$$
this gives us:

$$a_{1}r_{11} + b_{1} = a_{2}r_{12} + b_{2} = c_{1}\\
a_{1}r_{21} + b_{1} = a_{2}r_{22} + b_{2} = c_{2}$$

From these equations I get:

$$a_{2} = a_{1}\frac{(r_{11} - r_{21})}{(r_{12} - r_{22})}; \quad b_{2}=b_{1} + a_{1}\frac{(r_{11} - r_{21})(r_{11} - r_{12})}{(r_{12} - r_{22})}$$

This helps in the iterative method, but I would like to generalize it for a bigger matrix. Can this be solved with Mathematica?

**UPDATE**

I have added two reproducible Python codes that should be helpful for a $2 \times 2$ matrix:

#### Code 1

```
import numpy as np
R = np.matrix([[2.5, 2.9], [2.3, 2.7]])
m = R.shape[0]
n = R.shape[1]
A = np.matrix(np.zeros(shape=(n,n)))
B = np.matrix(np.zeros(shape=(m,n)))
A[0,0] = 1
B[0,0] = 1
k = 0
for i in range (1, 10000):
    A[0,0] = A[0, 0] - 0.0000001
    B[0,0] = B[0, 0] - 0.0000001
    for j in range(1, n):
        A[j, j] = A[(j-1), (j-1)] * ((R[0, 0] - R[1, 0]) / (R[0, 1] - R[1, 1]))
        B[0, j] = B[0, 0] + A[0, 0] * (((R[0, 0] - R[1, 0]) / (R[0, 1] - R[1, 1])) * (R[0, 0] - R[0, 1]))
        B[1, 0] = B[0, 0]
        B[1, j] = B[0, 0] + A[0, 0] * (((R[0, 0] - R[1, 0]) / (R[0, 1] - R[1, 1])) * (R[0, 0] - R[0, 1]))
    C = R * A + B
    C_convergence = np.all(np.all(np.diff(C, axis = 1) == 0, axis = 1), axis = 0)
    k = k + 1
    print k
print C
```

#### Code 2

```
import numpy as np
R = np.matrix([[2.5, 2.9], [2.3, 2.7]])
m = R.shape[0]
n = R.shape[1]
A = np.matrix(np.zeros(shape=(n,n)))
B = np.matrix(np.zeros(shape=(m,n)))
A[0,0] = 1
B[0,0] = 1
k = 0
C_convergence = False
k = 0
while C_convergence == False:
    A[0,0] = A[0, 0] - 0.0000001
    B[0,0] = B[0, 0] - 0.0000001
    for j in range(1, n):
        A[j, j] = A[(j-1), (j-1)] * ((R[0, 0] - R[1, 0]) / (R[0, 1] - R[1, 1]))
        B[0, j] = B[0, 0] + A[0, 0] * (((R[0, 0] - R[1, 0]) / (R[0, 1] - R[1, 1])) * (R[0, 0] - R[0, 1]))
        B[1, 0] = B[0, 0]
        B[1, j] = B[0, 0] + A[0, 0] * (((R[0, 0] - R[1, 0]) / (R[0, 1] - R[1, 1])) * (R[0, 0] - R[0, 1]))
    C = R * A + B
    C_convergence = np.all(np.all(np.diff(C, axis = 1) == 0, axis = 1), axis = 0)
    k = k + 1
    print k
print C
```

Comment: In the 2x2 example you have 4 equations and 6 values to solve for `{a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2}`. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, but {a1, a2, b1, b2} are initial guesses and I shall iterate it till I get a converged {c1, c2}.

Comment: Could you please exemplify your iteration process with a numerical example in the 2x2 case? I just get an exact solution with 2 degrees of freedom in one step

Comment: I tried in Python which is provided in the update.

Answer (score 3):

This can be handled by Solve straightforwardly:

```
r = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {2, 2}];
a = {{a1, 0}, {0, a2}};
b = {{b1, b2}, {b1, b2}};
c = {{c1, c1}, {c2, c2}};
Solve[r.a + b == c, {a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2}]

{{a2 -> 18 a1, b2 -> -45 a1 + b1, c1 -> -9 a1 + b1, c2 -> 9 a1 + b1}}
```

You can interpret this as saying that for any a1 and b1, the other parameters, if calculated this way, will fulfill your equation.